# How i can add id to foreign key same row when insert

Tags: mysql

I have a database that looks like this:

| `id` | `name` | `id_name` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | News | 1 |

In this table:

- `id` is primary key
- `id_name` is foreign key, GET data from same table (`id`)

How, when I insert (`name`), can the (`id_name`) insert same `id` row directly by PHP PDO?

Comment: you cannot. need another update query.

Comment: maybe you can use triggers

Comment: Also, PDO is not a database. It cannot do anything  mysql can't do. So you have to find a solution to your problem in raw mysql and then only then port it to PHP

Comment: It is not suggested to do it automatically like this, since a foreign key will be a Primary key or a key of some kind in another table. having it auto-increment or be the same as your primary key can cause you problems. those should be insterted/updated in the correct sequence depending your schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
<?php
$categories = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `article_categories` ORDER BY id DESC");
$categories->execute();
$categories = $categories->fetchObject();

$id = $categories->id + 1;

$array = array($id, $id_language, $id, $name, $sort, $status);

$rows = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `article_categories`  (`id`,`id_language`,`id_categories`, `name`, `sort`, `status`) VALUES (?,?,?, ?, ?, ?)");

$rows->execute($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a procedure that you use to insert that would create the parent automatically but this raises more questions: who should the parents parent be? what is the parents name? It would be better to choose an existing parent when you create the child, if need be create the parent first.
We cannot use a trigger because a trigger cannot insert into the table which is being modified as it is mutating and therefore blocked.
If you want your client interface could present creation of parent and child as one operation but you have to insert the child after the parent. See below.

> ```
> create table t (
> id int  primary key,
> name varchar(25),
> id_name int ,
> constraint fk_id_name foreign key (id_name) references t(id),
> constraint ck_not_Self check (id<>id_name or id = 1));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into t value(1,'News',1)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into t values(2,'two',2)
> ```
>
> ```
> Check constraint 'ck_not_Self' is violated.
> ```

> ```
> insert into t values(2,'two',1)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into t values(4,'four',3),(3,'three',2);
> ```
>
> ```
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_131033813`.`t`, CONSTRAINT `fk_id_name` FOREIGN KEY (`id_name`) REFERENCES `t` (`id`))
> ```

> ```
> insert into t values(3,'three',2),(4,'four',3);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0db98929252e919b755890da816aa0a6)*

Comment: (id) is primary key , How i can know what is (id) number when insert data?

Comment: Is id an automatically incremented column or do you enter the number?

Comment: automatically increment